How to pass a JsonifyObject<T> returned from Remix's useLoaderData<typeof loader> to a function
From the Remix 2.9.2 route code below, I get the TypeScript error...

Argument of type 'JsonifyObject<IdAndDate>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdAndDate'.

...and I can't figure out how to import JsonifyObject.
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";

type IdAndDate = {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
};

export default function Component() {
  //
  const idAndDate = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  // this line would work great, and helpfully, idAndDate.date is typed as string because it was serialized...
  //return (<div>{idAndDate.id}: {idAndDate.date}</div>);

  // but this, doesn't work because --
  // "Argument of type 'JsonifyObject<IdAndDate>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdAndDate'."
  // -- which is true, but I can't figure out how to import JsonifyObject :\
  return <div>{formatIdAndDate(idAndDate)}</div>;
}

export function loader(): IdAndDate {
  return { id: 42, date: new Date() };
}

function formatIdAndDate(idAndDate: IdAndDate): string {
  return `${idAndDate.id}: ${idAndDate.date}`;
}


I tried...
import { JsonifyObject } from "@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/jsonify"

...but get the error...

Module '"@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/jsonify"' declares 'JsonifyObject' locally, but it is not exported.

...which makes sense because it's not exported -- but I can't find anywhere else to import it from.
I don't want to use as IdAndDate because that will give up the really helpful fact that JsonifyObject knows that the date is a string after the object gets serialized.
(Also, I know the example is trivial and doesn't need a function, but this is simplified to show the core of the problem. In the real code, there is more elaborate logic that does make sense to be done on the browser side.)
Am I missing something simple? Is JsonifyObject exported somewhere else I can't find?

In your loader, you should be using the json helper.
return json({ id: 42, date: new Date() })

Then in your UI component, useLoaderData will return your data with the JsonifyObject type.
EDIT: I may have misunderstood your question.
You can use the SerializeFrom type helper to give you the serialized type.
type SerializedIdAndDate = SerializeFrom<IdAndDate>

// or

type SerializedIdAndDate = SerializeFrom<typeof loader>


At first I couldn't find SerializeFrom and tried importing Jsonify from @remix-run/server-runtime/dist/jsonify, which is where JsonifyObject is located, and that worked. I then found SerializeFrom in @remix-run/node, which also worked. Is SerializeFrom preferred? Any guidance on why? In any case — thank you!

What if I just want to use my own type (IdAndDate in this example). I have components thta accept my type, I don't want to have them all use this serialized type.

@Joe, I posted an answer both with the code implied by this answer and also with another version of the code that shows a different option that would work for components that accept the unserialized type — the simple answer is that you need to adapt the serialized type back to the original type

If you want to use native types then I suggest you use my package remix-typedjson. Or you can use the me Single Data Fetch feature in Remix where it natively supports all types.

thank you so much! This should really be in the remix docs

This answer is just in case anyone might be helped by seeing the working code using the suggestion from the accepted answer:
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { SerializeFrom } from "@remix-run/node";

type IdAndDate = {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
};

export default function Component() {
  const idAndDate = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  return <div>{formatIdAndDate(idAndDate)}</div>;
}

export function loader(): IdAndDate {
  return { id: 42, date: new Date() };
}

function formatIdAndDate(idAndDate: SerializeFrom<IdAndDate>): string {
  return `${idAndDate.id}: ${idAndDate.date}`;
}

The next code block is an alternative that answers Joe's comment on the accepted answer.
Here, the serialized object is converted back into the original datatype by adapting anything that got serialized to a different type back into the original type. In my simple example, only the Date needs adapted back.
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";

type IdAndDate = {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
};

export default function Component() {
  const serializedIdAndDate = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const idAndDate = { id: serializedIdAndDate.id, date: new Date(serializedIdAndDate.date) };
  return <div>{formatIdAndDate(idAndDate)}</div>;
}

export function loader(): IdAndDate {
  return { id: 42, date: new Date() };
}

// this function now can use the original unserialized type
function formatIdAndDate(idAndDate: IdAndDate): string {
  return `${idAndDate.id}: ${idAndDate.date}`;
}


Thanks for addressing my comment. I was hoping there was a way to automatically convert dates, but I think it is impossible (without adding a separate library) according to this https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/634.
